# I am unable to write this asp code

Tags: asp.net, loops, html-table

I have this C.A.T. where I am supposed to answer several questions using asp.net.
I recently posted one which has no answer yet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43092347/im-unable-to-debug-my-asp-code-below).

This current one requires to create a table with with 4 columns and 5 rows using for loop. I have taken a screen shot of the question and included it.

[image: question]

The code I have managed so far is:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <%
    'dim i
    'for i=0 to 24
    'Response.write(i &"<br/>")
    'next

        'this is some new code


         %>
        <table border="1">
            <%
        for i=0 to 24

        %>
        <tr>
            <td><% response.write(i) %></td>        
        </tr>    

        <%

        next
    %>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Someone help please.

Comment: You will need to create *two* loops: one for the 5 rows which repeats the loop for the 5 columns within the row. Try and get the basic shape, then worry about the exact numbers. Good luck!

Comment: I'm new in asp @Kesting. Would you help with some code, please?

Comment: By the way, is this "ASP" (a.k.a. "ASP Classic") or "ASP.Net"?

Answer (score 0):

Sample code for the two loops needed:

```
For row As Integer = 0 To 4
    For column As Integer = 0 To 4
        Console.Write(String.Format("r{0}c{1} ", row, column))
    Next
    Console.WriteLine
Next
```

You still have to (1) integrate this into your ASP code (Hint: replace the Console.Write/.WriteLine) and (2) go from `row` and `column` to the number you need.